# Android Fountain Library - Type inference failed: Cannot infer type parameter NetworkValue in fun createNetworkWithCacheSupportListing

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, datasource

I am trying to use Fountain (https://github.com/xmartlabs/fountain) in order to help me handle pagination and local/remote data source.

I am calling an internal function of the library like this:

```
FountainRx.createNetworkWithCacheSupportListing(
networkDataSourceAdapter = networkDataSourceAdapter,
cachedDataSourceAdapter = cachedDataSourceAdapter,
firstPage = FountainConstants.DEFAULT_FIRST_PAGE,
ioServiceScheduler = Schedulers.io(),
ioDatabaseScheduler = Schedulers.io(),
pagedListConfig = FountainConstants.DEFAULT_PAGED_LIST_CONFIG)
```

But I get just this compiler error:

```
Type inference failed: Cannot infer type parameter NetworkValue in fun <NetworkValue, DataSourceValue> createNetworkWithCacheSupportListing(networkDataSourceAdapter: RxNetworkDataSourceAdapter<out ListResponse<out NetworkValue>>, cachedDataSourceAdapter: CachedDataSourceAdapter<NetworkValue, DataSourceValue>, ioServiceScheduler: Scheduler = ..., ioDatabaseScheduler: Scheduler = ..., firstPage: Int = ..., pagedListConfig: PagedList.Config = ...): Listing<DataSourceValue>

None of the following substitutions 
(RxNetworkDataSourceAdapter<out ListResponse<out BeerListResponse<List<Beer>>>>,CachedDataSourceAdapter<BeerListResponse<List<Beer>> Any?>,Scheduler,Scheduler,Int,PagedList.Config)
(RxNetworkDataSourceAdapter<out ListResponse<out List<Beer>>>,CachedDataSourceAdapter<List<Beer>, Any?>,Scheduler,Scheduler,Int,PagedList.Config) 

can be applied to
(RxNetworkDataSourceAdapter<BeerListResponse<List<Beer>>>,CachedDataSourceAdapter<BeerListResponse<List<Beer>>, Beer>,Int,Scheduler,Scheduler,PagedList.Config))
```

Any idea of what could be the problem?

Below you can find the code that creates the RxNetworkDataSourceAdapter:

```
private fun createNetworkDataSourceAdapter(): RxNetworkDataSourceAdapter<BeerListResponse<List<Beer>>> {
        val pageFetcher = object : RxPageFetcher<BeerListResponse<List<Beer>>> {
            override fun fetchPage(page: Int, pageSize: Int): Single<BeerListResponse<List<Beer>>> =
                remoteSource.getBeers(page = page, pageSize = pageSize)
        }
        return pageFetcher.toTotalEntityCountNetworkDataSourceAdapter()
    }
```

If you need further info, just let me know!
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! Was, as the compiler was saying, a type inference problem.

With the following code:

```
override fun getAllBeers(): Listing<Beer> {
        val networkDataSourceAdapter: RxNetworkDataSourceAdapter<out BeerListResponse<out List<Beer>>> = createNetworkDataSourceAdapter()
        val cachedDataSourceAdapter: CachedDataSourceAdapter<List<Beer>,Beer> = getBeerLocalSource()
        return FountainRx.createNetworkWithCacheSupportListing(
            networkDataSourceAdapter = networkDataSourceAdapter,
            cachedDataSourceAdapter = cachedDataSourceAdapter,
            firstPage = FountainConstants.DEFAULT_FIRST_PAGE,
            ioServiceScheduler = Schedulers.io(),
            ioDatabaseScheduler = Schedulers.io(),
            pagedListConfig = FountainConstants.DEFAULT_PAGED_LIST_CONFIG)
    }
```

Using the out kotlin keyword to explicit the types, the error message is finally gone.

More info in this Kotlin Documentation page: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html